# Sonata Seo Bundle: busco más documentación

Tags: seo, symfony4

Recientemente he instalado Sonata Seo Bundle. Siguiendo la documentación oficial en:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/seo/2-x/doc/reference/usage.html

donde dice: "However, it is possible to alter these values at runtime:" y el siguiente archivo:

```
<?php

$post = $this->getPostManager()->findOneByPermalink($permalink, $this->container->get('sonata.news.blog'));

$seoPage = $this->container->get('sonata.seo.page');

$seoPage
    ->setTitle($post->getTitle())
    ->addMeta('name', 'description', $post->getAbstract())
    ->addMeta('property', 'og:title', $post->getTitle())
    ->addMeta('property', 'og:type', 'blog')
................
```

La pregunta es sencilla: donde se ubica este archivo y donde encuentro documentación más extensa donde aparezca explicada cada una de esas variables?

Gracias

Comment: "ese archivo" es tu controlador. Lo que hace es manipular el servicio sonata.seo.page para añadir los datos que a ti te interesan. Luego en la plantilla, el helper accede al mismo servicio y coje lo que has definido.

Comment: Gracias Jakala por tu explicación. Conoces alguna documentación o algún ejemplo desarrollado que utilice Sonata Seo Bundle? Gracias de nuevo